# is this a thread deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

I wanted to intentionally do/test java thread deadlock state so I made a following sample code:

```
public class TestDeadLock extends Thread{
    private Integer a=new Integer(9);
    public void run(){

        if(Thread.currentThread().getName().equals("t1")){
            XXXX();
        }
        else{
            ZZZZ();
        }
    }

    public void XXXX(){
        System.out.println("inside XXXX");
        synchronized(a){
            a++;
            ZZZZ();
        }
        System.out.println("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        //ZZZZ();
    }

    public synchronized void ZZZZ(){
        System.out.println("inside ZZZZ");
        synchronized(a){
            a--;
            XXXX();
        }
        System.out.println("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        TestDeadLock tdl=new TestDeadLock();
        Thread t1=new Thread(tdl);
        Thread t2=new Thread(tdl);
        t1.setName("t1");
        t2.setName("t2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();

        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-="+tdl.a);
    }
}
```

The output came out to be like :

inside XXXX

inside ZZZZ

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=10

***output is NOT exiting.***

**I wanted to know, was it due to threads reached `Dead Lock` state? Is it a right example to experience `Dead Lock`.** Suggest or correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Could you add the exception being thrown to your question (inside a code block)? Otherwise, it's nearly impossible to decide what the error is.

Comment: No, this is a race condition.

Comment: Don’t edit your question to become an entirely different question. If you have a new question, open a new question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you are not experiencing a dead lock. You are encountering a `StackOverflowError` because you are running into an infinite loop.

Note that your method

```
public synchronized void ZZZZ() {
  System.out.println("inside ZZZZ");

    XXXX(); // run-time exception
}
```

is equivalent to

```
public void ZZZZ() {
  synchronized(this) {
    System.out.println("inside ZZZZ");

      XXXX(); // run-time exception
  }
}
```

You are not causing a dead lock because you are working on two different instances.
Thread 1 locks `t1`, thread 2 locks `t2`.

Comment: one thread occupies ZZZZ an at that time and before occupying XXXX methode, the other thread may occupy XXXX methode and then at that time the both threads wait for each other for an unlimited time before occur any stackoverflow error

Comment: No, sorry, that is not correct. One thread occupies the lock in ```ZZZZ``` on itself (``t1``) and the other thread occupies the lock on itself (``t2``).

Comment: you can not forecast if when the first thread is in XXXX and before riching zzzz, the other thread can take zzzz so will lock it and the other thread will wait for zzzz while the other is waiting for xxxx please think a little deep

Comment: No. Both threads are independent instances of the class ``TestDeadLock``. The thread named ``t1`` will always invoke ``XXXX()`` and acquire the necessary lock. The thread named ``t2`` will always invoke ``ZZZZ()`` on the instance ``t2`` (which is not yet locked) and acquire the lock. Try it out!

Comment: OMG I didn't attend to the code well and the both threads are independent instance of th class, I'm sorry you are right I'll delete answer to not be cause of misunderstanding

Comment: @Farhang Amary: Even if they were not independent, there was no deadlock. Since `XXXX` and `ZZZZ` are both instance methods calling each other on the *same* instance, there acquire the same lock that they already own. In that scenario one thread would get the lock and the other would have to wait until the former threw the `StackOverflowError` (which releases the lock).

Comment: @Holger yes I understood, many thanks. I was in hurry when reading the code

Comment: @Holger,@nrainer sorry for interrupting you guys again but can just check out if this is a case of dead lock or not : [here](http://snipsave.com/user/profile/ajay#9764)

Comment: No, this is not a deadlock because locks are **reentrant** in Java. Thread ``t1`` invokes ``XXXX()``, locks ``9``, invokes ``ZZZZ()``, locks ``10``, invokes ``XXXX()`` and does not need to get the lock on ``9`` because it holds it already. ``t2`` is again fully independent. Try it out!

Comment: @nrainer , wow.. `it holds it already.` What a super comment. It vanished all doubts from my mind. Thanks dear. :)

Comment: @Farhang: misunderstandings like this happen to us all, it's hard to slow down and read carefully.

Answer (score 3):

Your ZZZZ() method contains a call to XXXX() method and vice-versa.
Thus, you have created a never-ending chain of calls that goes: ZZZZ() -> XXXX() -> ZZZZ() -> XXXX() -> etc.

Eventually, your stack will grow too large from all the nested method calls that get pushed onto the stack. Hence, the exceptions that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example:

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock2) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 2...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 1...");
            synchronized (Lock1) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

This accurately shows threads reaching deadlock.

Here is the solution:

```
public class TestThread {
   public static Object Lock1 = new Object();
   public static Object Lock2 = new Object();

   public static void main(String args[]) {

      ThreadDemo1 T1 = new ThreadDemo1();
      ThreadDemo2 T2 = new ThreadDemo2();
      T1.start();
      T2.start();
   }

   private static class ThreadDemo1 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 1: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 1: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   }
   private static class ThreadDemo2 extends Thread {
      public void run() {
         synchronized (Lock1) {
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1...");
            try { Thread.sleep(10); }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            System.out.println("Thread 2: Waiting for lock 2...");
            synchronized (Lock2) {
               System.out.println("Thread 2: Holding lock 1 & 2...");
            }
         }
      }
   } 
}
```

Source: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_thread_deadlock.htm

Comment: Let's make the world of coding a little less confusing.

Comment: I hope you didn't mind. I copy pasted that from your account's `about` panel ;)

Answer (score -1):

Example given by Jase Pellerin is a good example of dead lock but it has one mistake (Sorry Jase Pellerin , i am sure you did it unintetionally) . Here, both methods are trying to get hold of `Lock1` first and then `Lock2`. I think it should be other way around.

```
Thread1{

synchronized (Lock1) {

synchronized (Lock2) {}

}
}

Thread2{

 synchronized (Lock2) {

 synchronized (Lock1) {}

 }
 }
```